# How to decrypt a file in virtual memory in C

Tags: encryption, c, virtual-memory

I'm trying to decrypt a file in memory and this file was encrypted with openssl.
For doing that, i use mmap for loading my encrypted file in memory like that:

```
void* src = mmap(0, statbuf.st_size,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

and duplicate it because i don't want to modify my original file

```
void* dst = mmap(0, statbuf.st_size,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
memcpy (dst, src, statbuf.st_size);
```

At this step all is ok but i don't know what to do next.
Initialy for testing purpose, i encrypt my file with the openssl command :

```
system("openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in my_encryptedfile -out my_encryptedfile.enc -pass")
```

and decrypt it with this command:

```
system("openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in my_encryptedfile.enc -out my_encryptedfile -pass pass:")
```

But i can't use dst in this case, so i search and discovered EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption.
[link here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption)

Then i encrypted and decrypted my file with that code [github code](https://github.com/kulkarniamit/openssl-evp-demo/blob/master/openssl_evp_demo.c)

I try using Key and IV and the decryption in memory and it seem working but i have a problem that i don't understand. When i dump the buffer of my decripted file, i saw "SPACES/NULS" at the end of the file and i don't figure out why it display that. When i try to execute my binany in memory by calling this function :

> func()

i got a segmentation fault

Any clues?

```
typedef void (*JittedFunc)(void);

void* alloc_writable_memory(void *ptr, size_t size) {
   ptr = mmap(0, size,
                   PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                   MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  if (ptr == (void*)-1) {
    perror("mmap");
    return NULL;
  }
  return ptr;
}

int make_memory_executable(void* m, size_t size) {
  if (mprotect(m, size, PROT_READ |PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC) == -1) {
    perror("mprotect");
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int do_crypt(char *in, char *out, int do_encrypt, int inlen)
{
  /* Allow enough space in output buffer for additional block */
  unsigned char  outbuf[inlen + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
  int outlen;
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
  /* Bogus key and IV: we'd normally set these from
  * another source.
  */
  unsigned char key[] = "0123456789abcdeF";
  unsigned char iv[] = "1234567887654321";
  //int n;
printf("step1\n");
  /* Don't set key or IV right away; we want to check lengths */
  ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
  printf("step2\n");
  EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, NULL, NULL,do_encrypt);
  printf("step3\n");
  OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_key_length(ctx) == 16);
  OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(ctx) == 16);

  /* Now we can set key and IV */
  EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv, do_encrypt);
  printf("step4\n");
      if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx, outbuf,&outlen, in, inlen))
        {
          printf("test 2.1: %d %d\n", inlen, outlen);
          printf("step8\n");
          /* Error */
          EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
          return 0;
        }

    //BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)outbuf, outlen);
    printf(" test 2: %d %d\n", inlen, outlen);

  if(!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf, &outlen))
    {
      printf("step11\n");

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
    }
//copy the decryted buffer in another memory space
    memcpy(out, outbuf, outlen);
    printf(" test 3: %d %d\n", inlen, outlen);
    //BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)outbuf, outlen);
    printf("step12\n");
    //fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, out);
    printf("step13\n");
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
  FILE *src, *dst;
  char *src_mem, *dst_mem, *dst2_mem = NULL;
  struct stat statbuf;
  int fd;

  src = fopen("hello_encrypted", "rb");
  if (!src) {
      /* Unable to open file for reading */
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: fopen error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      return errno;
  }
  /*get the file des from a file*/
  fd = fileno(src);

  /* find size of input file */
  if (fstat (fd,&statbuf) < 0)
    {printf ("fstat error");
     return 0;
    }

  /* go to the location corresponding to the last byte */
  if (lseek (fd, statbuf.st_size - 1, SEEK_SET) == -1)
    {printf ("lseek error");
     return 0;
    }
  if ((src_mem = mmap (0, statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == (caddr_t) -1)
      {
        printf ("mmap error for input");
        return 0;
      }
  if ((dst_mem = mmap (0,  statbuf.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS , -1, 0)) == (caddr_t) -1)
    {
      printf ("mmap error for output");
      return 0;
    }

    if ((dst2_mem = mmap (0,  statbuf.st_size , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
      MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS , -1, 0)) == (caddr_t) -1)
      {
        printf ("mmap error for output");
        return 0;
      }
    memcpy(dst_mem, src_mem, statbuf.st_size);

    int n;
    /* 0 for decrypting or 1 for encrypting*/
    n = do_crypt(dst_mem,dst2_mem, 0, statbuf.st_size);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    make_memory_executable(dst2_mem, statbuf.st_size);
//dump of the decrypt binary
    BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)dst2_mem, statbuf.st_size);

//try to launch the decrypted binary ==> segmentation fault
   JittedFunc func = dst2_mem;
func();
  fclose(src);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your decryption function?

Comment: Can you specify `it doesn't work` ? Technically, if your computer is powered off, it won't work. More detail will make it easier for us or for SO to determine the problem and give you a suiting answer!

Comment: My guess is the problem is the key. `openssl enc -pass "pass:password"` runs "password" through a (very poor) key derivation function, whereas the code you linked needs the actual key rather than a password.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald+ is exactly right: `enc` by default does **password-based (derived)** encryption and decryption; for details see my answer at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption . Since you are using OpenSSL lib, you can just call **`EVP_BytesToKey`** to compute the key _and IV_ for `EVP_Cipher*` (or `EVP_Decrypt*`); without OpenSSL you would need to duplicate the functionality of `EVP_BytesToKey` but as I describe that's not difficult.

Comment: Thanks, i try using KEY and IV and the decryption it's working but why can't i execute my binary? when i try i get a segmenttion fault

Answer (score 0):

I would remove from the first mmap the flag PROT_WRITE, because you dont want to modify the original file, I think you can also use PROT_PRIV, but have a look to what says the man of mmap.

On the other hand for decrypt your buffer you can use many libraries (a lot of them based on openssl), I specially like CryptoPP but there are many others. Here is an example of how your code will look like on CryptoPP

```
try {
    // CryptoPP::ECB_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Decryption d;
    // CrypoPP::CBC_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Decryption d;
    CrypoPP::CBC_CTS_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Decryption d;
    // What ever mode is best for you

    d.SetKey(key.data(), key.size());

    // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
    //  padding as required.
    CryptoPP::StringSource s((const uint8_t*)dst, length_dst, true,
            new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(d,
                    new CryptoPP::StringSink(recovered)
            ) // StreamTransformationFilter
    ); // StringSource
} catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e) {
    std::cout << "ERROR decrypting:" << e.what() << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: I sure hope you don't _actually_ use ECB mode.

Comment: _But penguins are so beautiful... If I don't use ECB, people will not point me to the Tux image on Wikipedia..._

Comment: Tux page on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_(ECB)

Comment: Thats C++ ? The OP asked a c specific problem.